# Efficiently implementing chamfer's distance as a loss for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to implement Chamfer's distance as a loss for my Tensorflow model, but it's very computationally impractical. Is there a more efficient approach to the minimal running example below? (The input and output are of size (1, 216, 216, 3).

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class EulerResnetBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EulerResnetBlock, self).__init__()

        self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 1, padding='same')
        self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 1, padding='same')
        
    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        return tf.nn.relu(x + self.conv2b(tf.nn.relu(self.conv2a(input_tensor))))


# custom class for computing Chamfer's distance
class ChamfersDistance(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # y_true and y_pred size: (1, 216, 216, 3)
        cd = 0
        for i in range(216):
            for j in range(216):
                cd +=  tf.math.add(tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_pred[0,i,j,:]-y_true), axis=3))),
                                      tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_true[0,i,j,:]-y_pred), axis=3))))
        
        return cd
```

And the net:

```py
eulernet = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()

eulernet.add(EulerResnetBlock())
eulernet.add(EulerResnetBlock())
eulernet.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((46656, 3)))

eulernet.build(input_shape=(None,216,216,3))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=10e-2, momentum=0.5)
loss_func = ChamfersDistance()
eulernet.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss_func)
```

I think my implementation is OK since it's in TensorFlow so the automatic gradients work out, just I'm not sure why it's taking so slow in the first place.

--- edit:

I've ended up doing something different and having the network take as input shapes of sizes (1, 3) with the number of points being implemented via batches. This is done so that my network actually does what it was supposed to do (my first implementation was incorrect). Specifically I now have the following as my loss function, with tensorflow's functional API used to add this loss function to the model. This has been appropriately vectorised, too.

```py
def cd_so(y_pred, y_true):
    cd1 =  tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.sqrt(
           tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(
           tf.math.square(tf.reshape(y_pred, (batch_size, 1, 1, 3)) - y_true), axis=-1), axis=1)))
    cd2 =  tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.sqrt(
           tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(
           tf.math.square(tf.reshape(y_true, (batch_size, 1, 1, 3)) - y_pred), axis=-1), axis=1)))
    return cd1 + cd2
```

Comment: What is `inp_small`? I don't see it defined anywhere in your code. As a rule of thumb in TF, avoid using `for` loops, try to use broadcasting instead if you can. As it is now, your code path defaults to eager-execution, which is really slow compared to graph-mode.

Comment: as far as I know, it's used as metrics usually, not as loss, mainly due to the fact that is very hard to optimize, and also to compute

Comment: there are ways to compute the pairwise distance between a set of N dimensional points in TF, but you will have (216x216)^2 elements in the resulting matrix, and this for each sample of your batch... pretty sure that will be still slow and you will run in OOM in a second

Comment: @Lescurel Good catch! Fixed. You mention eager execution - I suspect that this is purely due to the lack of the tf.function decorator instead of the double for loops?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia "Unfortunately" I am trying to self-implement a paper in which they use this as part of the loss function, so I don't particularly want to drop it! Maybe they had more than a laptop though :p.

Comment: @baubel yes, you can use `@tf.function` to transform it to a graph, however all the functions called to a tf.fcuntions are automatically transformed to it, so I'm pretty sure that keras is already doing it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, it's slow by definition. Given 2 sets, you have a loop (2 since input is 2 dims), and then some O(n) operations, so your loss is at least O(n^2)...

Given this, we can see that with two 216x216 images, you will have a matrix pairwise distance that is (216x216)^2, that considering that you probably will use float32 as type, it will consume:

```
216 * 216 * 216 * 216 * 32 = 69 Gb
```

this, for each pair of images, thus if you have batches of 10 images (which is pretty small), considering that you will use around 690 gigabytes of memory

This, without considering:

- the time it takes to fill that matrix
- that Tensor in TF are limited to 2GB of size.

Now, either the paper that you are considering used images with size in the order of 50x50, and still the distance matrix is pretty big and slow to compute, or they used an iterative algorithm you are doing.

About the implementation, I tried a parallelized version of your code:

```
# custom class for computing Chamfer's distance
class ChamfersDistanceVect(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # y_true and y_pred size: (1, 216, 216, 3)
        dim1 = y_true.shape[1]
        dim2 = y_true.shape[2]
        mat1 = np.reshape(np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.linspace(0,dim1-1,dim1, dtype="float32"), -1), dim2, axis=1), -1)
        mat2 = np.reshape(np.repeat(np.transpose(np.expand_dims(np.linspace(0,dim2-1,dim2, dtype="float32"), -1)), dim2, axis=0), -1)
        indexes = np.transpose(np.stack((mat1, mat2)))
        def dist (index):
            i,j = tf.cast(index, tf.int32).numpy()
            return tf.math.add(tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_pred[0,i,j,:]-y_true), axis=3))),
                        tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_min(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_true[0,i,j,:]-y_pred), axis=3))))
        res = tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.map_fn(dist, indexes)
        )
        return res
```

It is faster during the first run, since it's Graph is easier to build, but it's slower after that, in particular, those are the numbers (using only ONE image with size 50x50):

- sequential version: first run (so with Graph creation) 21 seconds, then 12
- vectorized version: first run 12 seconds, then 9 seconds

---

Given everything said, either you allow TF to implement the Graph during the first run, and thus the first run will take much longer than the following ones, or you have to reduce your input size significantly

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to change my network to be more efficient overall, now it takes as input points (1, 3), and has a loss function that explicitly works with the batchsize to compute loss over the batch elements. Therefore the shapes to work with are of size (batch_size, 1, 3), which for shape with 500 vertices works out OK. I ended up using your idea to improve on my loss function without having a `for` loop.

Comment: @baubel perfect, glad to see it helped